# Python replace() function not working - although in a new function

Tags: python, str-replace

I'm making a function that changes characters to `x[alphabet number]/` using the `replace` function.
Right now it looks like this:

```
def compile(File):
    f=open(File,'r') #open the file parameter
    content=f.read() #create the content variable.
    a=content.replace('a','x1/').replace('b','x2/').replace('c','x3/').replace('d','x4/').replace('e','x5/').replace('f','x6/').replace('g','x7/')... # and so on.
    print(a)
```

This will be the output:

```
x24/13/x24/1/x24/11/x24/5/x32/x27/x24/6/x24/21/x24/14/x24/3/x24/20/x24/9/x24/15/x24/14/x28/x32/x24/19/x24/1/x25/x32/'Hx24/9/x30/'x29/x24/1/x24/19/x24/11/x32/'Ux24/19/x24/5/x24/18/x24/14/x24/1/x24/13/x24/5/x28/x32/'x29/x24/1/x24/19/x24/11/x32/'Px24/1/x24/19/x24/19/x24/23/x24/15/x24/18/x24/4/x28/x32/'
```

So that is what I wanted, but then if I want to change it back, it won't work.

```
def decompile():
    comp=open(run,'r').read()
    a=comp.replace('x1/','a').replace('x2/','b').replace('x3/','c').replace('x4/','d').replace('x5/','e').replace('x6/','f').replace('x7/','g')... #and so on.
    print(a)
```

But now, this will be the output.

```
x13/x1/x11/x5/ $x6/x21/x14/x3/x20/x9/x15/x14/: x19/x1/y 'Hx9/!' | x1/x19/x11/ 'Ux19/x5/x18/x14/x1/x13/x5/: ' | x1/x19/x11/ 'Px1/x19/x19/x23/x15/x18/x4/: '
$x6/x21/x14/x3/x20/x9/x15/x14/
```

Why is this?

Comment: You don't give the original input - can you pinpoint the exact place where the final output is different? But in general terms, the problem will be that your replacements are done one at a time rather than all at once, so in the "decompile" phase, for example, `x24/25/` will become first `x25/` and then simply `y`, when I assume you might just want `x25/` as the result?

Comment: Hey there, first, can you give us the input? second, can you please explain where in the process is it going to be written back to a file? (I'm inferring that's the case because you said 'change it back'). Third, I think this is not a good idea to do what you are doing with all those replace func. IMO you should iterate through string and build a new string according to your rules...

Comment: As a side note, this is a painful way to accomplish this.  There are alternatives that let you address all characters systematically.  For example: re.sub('[a-z]', lambda x: f'x{ord(x.group(0)) - ord("a")+1}/', comp)

Comment: @AaronBentley, yeah. I know it was a painful way to do that. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the Regex module

```
import re

def compile(content):
  return re.sub(r'[a-z]', lambda match: f"x{ord(match.group())-ord('a')+1}/", content)

def decompile(content):
  return re.sub(r'x(\d+)/', lambda match: chr(int(match.group(1))-1+ord('a')), content)

g = "a13bc35defg"
r = compile(g)
print(r)
print(decompile(r))
```

Do not put the file reading in your `compile` and `decompile` functions.

Answer (score -1):

```
def compile(a):
    content= a
    a=content.replace('a','x1/').replace('b','x2/').replace('c','x3/').replace('d','x4/').replace('e','x5/').replace('f','x6/').replace('g','x7/')# and so on.
    print(a) 

def decompile(b):
    comp= b
    s=comp.replace('x1/','a').replace('x2/','b').replace('x3/','c').replace('x4/','d').replace('x5/','e').replace('x6/','f').replace('x7/','g')
    print(b) 

g = "abcdefg"
compile(g)
decompile(g)
```

This code works perfect, do the same thing just instead of a string add the file.